# Component tree vs view hierarchy in Angular

Tags: angular

The ["View Hierarchy"](https://angular.io/guide/glossary#view-hierarchy) section of the Angular glossary contains the passage

> [A] view hierarchy doesn't imply a component hierarchy. Views that are embedded in the context of a particular hierarchy can be host views of other components.

I'm not sure what this passage is trying to say, especially since the example given sounds awfully like a component tree. In what cases would a view hierarchy not  imply a component tree?

Comment: Read these articles may be you will get some insights. https://blog.angularindepth.com/these-5-articles-will-make-you-an-angular-change-detection-expert-ed530d28930

Comment: View is created either from a component factory or templateRef, so if you have an embedded view created from a templateRef as a child of component, you'll have a hierarchy of two views with only one component.